# Python3: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

Python3: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, is it because the way I called the method `.area()` is wrong? Or is it because the way I def the `.area()` is wrong? Thank you

```
class Rectangle: 
    def __init__ (self):
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0
        self.area = 0

    def setData(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def area(self, height, width):
        self.area = height * width

    def __str__(self):
        return "height = %i, width = %i" % (self.height, self.width)
        return "area = %i" % self.area

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r1 = Rectangle()
    print (r1)
    r1.setData(3,4)
    print (r1)
```

Here I call `.area()`, I think what's where the problem comes from:

```
    r1.area(3,4)
    print (r1)
```

Comment: Which line? Can you show the error message?

Comment: Why do you define `__str__` twice?

Comment: better to call the method setArea, or if the input is empty/None have "get" behavior and if there is a value have "set" behavior.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you first defined a variable `area` (an integer to be specific) as an attribute of your class `Rectangle`, and later a function `area()`.

This inconsistency causes confusion so the Python interpreter tries to call the interger as a function which fails. Just rename one of the integer variable (`self.area = ...`) or the function (`def area(...)`), and everything should work fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have name collision between the `area` method and the `area` field. It looks like you dont need the area field at all. And the arguments of the area function are not used. And you have two `__str__` functions too. I attempted to fix it:

```
class Rectangle: 
    def __init__ (self):
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0

    def setData(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        return "height = %i, width = %i" % (self.height, self.width)

    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.width

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r1 = Rectangle()
    print (r1)
    r1.setData(3,4)
    print (r1)
    print ("area = ", r1.area())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def area(self, height, width):
    self.area = self.height * self.width
```

You are defining a method `area` and inside the method you overwrite it with an `int`.